# How to connect to the services and registry from a another computer via batch file

Tags: batch-file, service, remote-registry

I would like to run a batch file that could open the services window and allows me to connect to another computer in order to restart a service on a remote machine. 
And a different batch file to remote a network registry located in the same domain.

Here are the steps that I'm trying to do using a batch file :

1. open "services.msc"
2. connect to another computer...
3. select computer name  (I will then type the computer name manually)
4. net start RemoteRegistry + Select Startup type to "Automatic"
5. open "regedit"
6. GO to File > Connect Network Registry > enter computer name (I will then type the computer name manually once again)
7. modify the following key : HKEY_Local_Machine>System>CurrentControlSet>services>LanManServer>Parameters

to [0] disable
or [1] enable

8. Restart "Server" services

Comment: If you're going to go through all that, why not just open a Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) to the other computer and click the mouse a few times instead? You'll do less typing and less work.

Comment: Yes Indeed but I will have to enforce a multiple RDP sessions to all Windows machines through a GPO, our policy does not allow it if a user is already logged in. I would rather automated this process.

Answer (score 0):

Type `sc /?`. This is built in to Windows. At it's most simple

```
sc \\server start service
```

Registry (`reg /?`) is the same but the computer name is part of the registry path.

```
REG QUERY \\server\HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ResKit\Nt\Setup /s
```